# Cannot install blazor via VSIX or extentions

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, blazor

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 and dotnet core 3.0.
When I try to search within the Visual Studio Extensions manager Blazor does not show up at all. When I try and install via the website: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor I receive the following error.

6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - -------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - 16.1.3132
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - -------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - Command line parameters:
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\ogre1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft.VisualStudio.BlazorExtension.16.0.19307.2.vsix
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - -------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
6/30/2019 10:07:13 PM - -------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Initializing Install...
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Extension Details...
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Identifier         : Microsoft.VisualStudio.BlazorExtension
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Name               : Blazor
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Author             : Microsoft
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Version            : 16.0.19307.2
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Description        : Provides Visual Studio support for Blazor
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Locale             : en-US
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     MoreInfoURL        : 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Certificate Info   : 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Serial Number] : 330000026ECE6AE5984BFC96A900000000026E
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Not Before]    : 9/6/2018 5:00:30 PM
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Not After]     : 9/6/2019 5:00:30 PM
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         [Thumbprint]    : 99B6246883B4B32EA59AE18B36945D205A876800
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Supported Products : 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -             Version : [16.2,)
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     References         : 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         -------------------------------------------------------
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         Name         : ASP.NET and web development tools
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -         Version      : [16.0,)
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Signature Details...
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM -     Extension is signed with a valid signature.
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - 
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Searching for applicable products...
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
6/30/2019 10:07:14 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

I have ran a repair on Visual Studio, and even uninstalled and reinstalled.

I was able to create a project before the latest Visual Studio update. After the update, that project, which was still just the base demo, would not build. When I went to make a new project, Blazor was no longer there.

Comment: I guess you are using the wrong version of VS.. which is it? Please check with the requirements.

Comment: See if there is a Community __Preview__ edition.

Comment: I may be missing it, but I am not seeing a preview version available.

Comment: @O.Watkins https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/